# Making text appear on top of the quote

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

Anybody have any ideas how to get my `h1` text to appear on top of the quote?

NOTE:

1. I don't want it to appear like the quote is before the H1 text, but on top of it.
2. The quote should appear without any additional markup or text in the HTML.

HTML

```
<div>
 <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
div:after {
    font-size: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content:'"';
    color: red;
}
h1 {
    padding: .5em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the `h1` a `z-index value`

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/auL2z/)

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
div:after {
    font-size: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content:'"';
    color: red;
}
h1 {
    padding: .5em;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried several different techniques, but the one thing I was missing was the position: relative; when I used z-indexing.

Answer (score 0):

`Absolute positioned` elements always show on top of relative elements. But you can fix it by adjusting the `z-index property`. Also adjust some positioning to tweak your result.

```
h1 {
    padding: .5em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -18px;
    left: -10px
}
```

**DEMO Here:** http://jsfiddle.net/zzLus/2/